# How can I split a string "a\n\nb" into c("a", "", "", "b")?

Tags: r, stringr, strsplit

When I `stringr::str_split` "\n\na\n" by "\n", I obtain `c("", "", "a", "")`.

I expected I can obtain `c("a", "", "", "b")` when I `stringr::str_split` "a\n\nb" by "\n", but I obtained `c("a", "", "b")` instead. How can I obtain `c("a", "", "", "b")` by splitting "a\n\n\a"?

Try:

```
stringr::str_split("a\n\nb", "\n")
```

Expect:

```
c("a", "", "", "b")
```

Result:

```
c("a", "", "b")
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that we want to extract each character separately, just split on the blank and remove all the `\n` to return blanks for the split elements

```
str_remove_all(strsplit(str1, "")[[1]], "\n")
[1] "a" ""  ""  "b"
```

---

Or use `perl = TRUE` with `\n?`

```
strsplit(str1, "\n?", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
[1] "a" ""  ""  "b"
```

---

If it should be at each `\n` only

```
strsplit(str_replace(str1, "(\n\\S)", "\n\\1"), "\n")[[1]]
[1] "a" ""  ""  "b"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "a\n\nb"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the correct result, even if it's not what you expect.  The length of the result equals the number of delimiters in the string + 1.  Thus if you want an extra field, you need to add an extra delimiter:

```
x1 <- "a\n\nb"
x2 <- "abc\n\ndef"

strsplit(gsub("(\n{2,})", "\\1\n", x1), "\n")[[1]]
[1] "a" ""  ""  "b"

strsplit(gsub("(\n{2,})", "\\1\n", x2), "\n")[[1]]
[1] "abc" ""    ""    "def"
```